# CWND max size in Linux

Tags: linux, tcp, congestion-control, cwnd

I've used this command below in Solaris to set the max CWND window size:

```
ndd -set /dev/tcp tcp_cwnd_max size_here
```

But I don't know the equivalent of it in Linux. Can anyone help me please? 
Note: I want to set the max size not the initial one.
Thank you in advance.